# How to get multiple rows in pgsql query result

Tags: postgresql

I'm using pgsql 9.3.
I have two tables which are identical. One is the master table and other is temp table. Every time there is an update, data is written to temp table, if data is not present in master then it is written into it. 
  
If there is only one entry in temp then i get desired result i.e, if that entry is not in master then it gets inserted. But in case where i have multiple rows in temp my logic fails.  Could any one help me on this.  
Below is the stataemnt I'm executing

```
select type, number, id, max(time) from testt t
       where not exists (
             select 1 from testm m
                  where (
                    m.id = t.id and m.type = t.type and m.number = t.number
                    and
                    ( 
                       m.time = (select max(m1.time) from testm m1 where m.id=m1.id
                     )
                  )
               )
            )
group by id, type, number;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  
  
Data in master table:

```
       type   |        number |              id |     time  
--------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------
     35817804 |        158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483336800000
     35817804 |        158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483337400000
     35817804 |        158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483338000000
     35817804 |        158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483338900000
```

Data in temp table:

```
  type   |        number |              id |     time
---------+---------------+-----------------+---------------
35817804 |        158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483339500000
35817804 |        158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483340100000
```

In temp, time is different for both the rows and these combination are not present in master. Hence both should be inserted into master making master as below

```
  type   |        number |              id |     time
---------+---------------+-----------------+---------------
35817804 |        158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483336800000
35817804 |        158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483337400000
35817804 |        158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483338000000
35817804 |        158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483338900000
35817804 |        158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483339500000
35817804 |        158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483340100000
```

But after running above mentioned query my master is populated with below data, missing last entry

```
  type   |        number |              id |     time
---------+---------------+-----------------+---------------
35817804 |        158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483336800000
35817804 |        158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483337400000
35817804 |        158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483338000000
35817804 |        158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483338900000
35817804 |        158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483339500000
```

Edit:
  
 Above statement is called in a procedure which adds respone of the query to master table

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Note: there is nothing inserted in your query. Do you want to add new records to the master table? then you'll need an insert statement somehiw.

Comment: Above statement is called in a procedure which inserts output in master table, sorry my bad I didn't mentioned it.

Comment: why max(time) in where condition?

Answer (score 0):

I've set up rextester example: http://rextester.com/TJLG3973

I used a CTE query avoiding the `select max(time)` in where condition. The LEFT JOIN used with `where m.type is null` returns nonexistent records.

```
with trecords as
(
    select t.type, t.number, t.id, max(t.time) as time
    from testt t
    group by t.type, t.number, t.id
)
insert into testm
select x.type, x.number, x.id, x.time
from trecords x
     left join testm m
     on m.type = x.type 
        and m.number = x.number 
        and m.id = x.id
        and m.time = x.time
where m.type is null
;
```

I've added two more lines to the temp table, just to check max(time) is working fine.

```
create temp table testt (type int, number int, id bigint, time bigint);
insert into testt values
(35817804, 158014, 262017400998389, 1483339500000),
(35817804, 158014, 262017400998389, 1483339600000),
(35817804, 158014, 262017400998389, 1483339700000),
(35817804, 158024, 262017400998389, 1483340100000);
```

And the master table supplied with the question:

```
create temp table testm (type int, number int, id bigint, time bigint);
insert into testm values
(35817804, 158014, 262017400998389, 1483336800000),
(35817804, 158024, 262017400998389, 1483337400000),
(35817804, 158014, 262017400998389, 1483338000000),
(35817804, 158024, 262017400998389, 1483338900000);
```

This is the final result:

```
+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
|   type   | number |        id       |      time     |
+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| 35817804 | 158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483336800000 |
+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| 35817804 | 158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483337400000 |
+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| 35817804 | 158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483338000000 |
+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| 35817804 | 158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483338900000 |
+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| 35817804 | 158024 | 262017400998389 | 1483340100000 |
+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| 35817804 | 158014 | 262017400998389 | 1483339700000 |
+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
```